# SVG data-uri background repeat in IE10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

I feel like I should be able to find an answer on this but, alas, I'm not having much luck. I'm trying to repeat an SVG as a background using a data-uri within CSS. It works in basically every browser except it doesn't seem to be working in IE10 (and probably other IE versions). The code is pretty simple really:

```
.bg-test {
    background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA1MCAxOCIgZW5hYmxlLWJhY2tncm91bmQ9Im5ldyAwIDAgNTAgMTgiPjxnIGZpbGw9IiNEMkQyRDIiPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wIDE3aDUwdjFoLTUwek0wIDBoNTB2MWgtNTB6TTAgMWgxdjE2aC0xek01IDE0aDF2M2gtMXpNMTAgMTNoMXY0aC0xek0xNSAxNGgxdjNoLTF6TTIwIDEzaDF2NGgtMXpNMjUgMTRoMXYzaC0xek0zMCAxM2gxdjRoLTF6TTM1IDE0aDF2M2gtMXpNNDAgMTNoMXY0aC0xek00NSAxNGgxdjNoLTF6Ii8+PC9nPjwvc3ZnPg==);
    height: 100px;
    background-repeat: x-repeat;
}
```

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Aaronius/C7p83/3/

It doesn't repeat in IE. Is this just a bug? Is there a decent workaround without resorting to raster images? Thanks.

Comment: http://r.va.gg/2012/05/data-uri-svg.html ?

Comment: Thanks Marc. I've narrowed the question to be specifically about the background repeating. Hopefully that gets over the hurdles mentioned in the link you shared.